# Related products tab is not adding in product info section on magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a product detail page. That page have product info tabs like description, review, product tags. I want to add related products tabs on that page in product into section. so I added the below code in local.xml file.

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>related</alias><title>Related Products</title><block>catalog/product_list_related</block><template>catalog/product/list/related.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

also I added the related products for a product like below.
Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Products -> choose any product -> Related Products tab. Here I searched the products by typing product name in name column and filtered and choose the products and saved. Please help me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ? taking it under group `detailed_info`

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info">
   <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" before="-">
       <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
       <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Related Products</value></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

** Code not tested, take the related product block and `addToParentGroup`:`Detailed_Info` and `Name the tab`